# How to Boost freshness documents with Lucene

Tags: search, lucene

i can set boost for indexing, but i don't to boost document by freshness document  (indexing by fields from databases)
code for boost:
titleq.setBoost(0.8f);
please help me for boosting  score by freshness document  thank.

Comment: I recommend that boost the document by freshness during the search rather than indexing

Answer (score 0):

There is one work around for your problem:

If you want latest updated document to come up then

Add one field with same value in every document and search document with that field and value pair.

So automatically your latest document will come up.